# Probability of No One Born on Day $j$

Tags: probability

Consider $n$ people in a room.
On an arbitrarily chosen day $j$, what is the probability no one was born?

$\textbf{My Question}$: Is my thought process correct?

Assuming the probability of any individual born on any given day is independent, consider two individuals, James and Sarah.

$P$(No one was born on day $j$)=$P$("James not born on day $j$")$P$("Sarah not born on day $j$").

On day $j$, the probability of a person being born is $\frac{1}{365}$.

Thus, $P$(No one was born on day $j$)=$(1-\frac{1}{365})$$(1-\frac{1}{365})$=$(\frac{364}{365})^2$.

For $n$, $P$(No one was born on day $j$)=$(\frac{364}{365})^n$.

Reference:
Blitzstein, J. K., & Hwang, J. (2014). $\textit{Introduction to probability.}$

Comment: Yeah, this is how I would do it too.

Comment: It's not clear that "day" refers to the day of the year, as opposed to a specific day (e.g., June 25, 2019). Also, keep in mind you may wish to handle leap years as well. In addition, you should state the assumption that all days are equally likely for a person to be born. Otherwise, as Matti P. wrote, I would also handle the problem basically as you're doing.

Comment: You should check out the Birthday Paradox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absolutely correct.

A more advanced question would be "What's the minimum number of people in the room for the probability of two of them having the same birthday to be larger than 50%?".  You will find an interesting answer.  Have fun!

Comment: thanks for the response!